# Is there a way to handle a single parameter as a build number OR source branch in an azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to allow for a single variable that can specify the build id or branch to deploy from.  This means I need to type coerce, and it's failing if I try to call a ge (greater than or equal) or lt (less than) on a string.  It looks like I might have to use bash commands to do the type conversion for me, so I was wondering if anyone had this handy.

Here's the steps I'm using:

```
- ${{ each deployment in parameters.deployments }}:
  - deployment: Deploy_${{deployment.serviceName}}_${{ parameters.region }}
    pool:
      vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
    displayName: 'Deploy ${{ deployment.serviceName }} ${{ parameters.region }}'
    ${{ if not(eq(parameters.kubernetesServiceEndpoint, '')) }}:
      environment: ${{ parameters.kubernetesServiceEndpoint }}
    ${{ elseif not(and(eq(parameters.azureResourceGroup, ''), eq(parameters.kubernetesCluster, ''))) }}:
      environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          # Disable the automatic downloading of artifacts, because we will specifying exactly what we need
          - download: none
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            condition:                        ${{ ge(0, deployment.branchBuildId) }}
            inputs:
              source:                         'specific'
              project:                        ${{ deployment.project }}
              pipeline:                       ${{ deployment.pipeline }}
              runVersion:                     'latestFromBranch'
              runBranch:                      ${{ deployment.branchBuildId }}
              patterns:                       'DeploymentData/*'
            displayName:                      'Download Latest Artifacts'
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            condition:                        ${{ lt(0, deployment.branchBuildId) }}
            inputs:
              source:                         'specific'
              project:                        ${{ deployment.project }}
              pipeline:                       ${{ deployment.pipeline }}
              runVersion:                     'specific'
              runId:                          ${{ deployment.branchBuildId }}
              #runBranch:                      ${{ deployment.branch }}
              patterns:                       'DeploymentData/*'
            displayName: 'Download Specific Artifacts (${{ deployment.buildId }})'
```

I want these to be mutually exclusive (run the first if pulling the latest from a specific branch, and run the second if downloading from a specific build id).  By using a single parameter I can avoid another control parameter to decide which version should be used.

Comment: Hi Derian, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1, If you use script to handle, then 'compile time usage' is unable to use.

You need to use runtime usage:

`variables['xxx']`

2, Variables only support passing string, you can compare them and then use logging command to output the result:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
parameters:
  - name: str1
    default: 110
  - name: str2
    default: 130
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: outputresult
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $str1 = "${{parameters.str1}}"
      $str2 = "${{parameters.str2}}"
      Write-Host $str1
      Write-Host $str2
      # powershell compare the strings greater than or less than
      if ($str1 -gt $str2) {
          $result = "greater than"
          Write-Host $result
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=result;isoutput=true]$result"
      } elseif ($str1 -lt $str2) {
          $result = "less than"
          Write-Host $result
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=result;isoutput=true]$result"
      } else {
          $result = "equal"
          Write-Host $result
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=result;isoutput=true]$result"
      }
#Below is the handling logic 
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq('greater than',variables['outputresult.result'])
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "greater than"
- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: eq('less than',variables['outputresult.result'])
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "less than"
```

Result:

[image]